# How to combine files of similar file names together in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, formatting, string-formatting

Imagine I have a folder with the following items :
default.xml    df_ak01.1001.jpg    df_ak01.1002.jpg    df_ak01.1003.jpg
df_ak01.1005.jpg    df_ak01.1006.jpg

(Here we can see that df_ak01.1004.jpg is missing which is very difficult to spot if there are thousands of files in the directory )
The program should be able to run on any directory and the file name part 
(here) df_ak01 can vary everytime . Can someone help me on this one .

I was able to get the current working directory where the program is currently being run , and I couldn't think of a logic how I could file name part if they're generic and mostly unknown.

I just created a regex to search for files with df_ak01 in their names and list them (But that's not a good way to do it). But still not successful how I'd implement finding the missing image.

```
import os
import re

current = os.getcwd()

#I've just implemented the listing of files that match 'df_ak01'
a = [x for x in os.listdir(current) if re.match('df_ak01.*.jpg',x)]
print a
```

So I'd like to get a output something like :

```
1 default.xml
3 df_ak01.%04d.jpg   1001-1003
2 df_ak01.%04d.jpg   1005-1006
```

Comment: Will all numbers be of length 4 or more, like 1001 and so on @NirmalKumar

Comment: Yes @DeveshKumarSingh . Mostly exactly 4 .

Comment: Hey @DeveshKumarSingh here we are hardcoding 'df_ak01' which is not the case in every case and can vary directory to directory. any idea how we can resolve this case.

Comment: Just define a dictionary of diretory to whatever is the value you want instead of `df_ak01`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I dont get it ! can you please explain

Comment: `{'dir1':'df_ak01','dir2':'df_ak02'}` etc where dir1 has files with df_ak01 prefix, dir2 has files with df_ak02 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows. Start with matching numbers with 4 or more digits, (the regex `"\d{4,}"` matches 4 or more digits) and extract all numbers. Then group consecutive numbers together using [more_itertools.consecutive_groups](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups), and create the result list, and then print it

```
import re
import os
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups
files = ["default.xml", "df_ak01.1001.jpg", "df_ak01.1002.jpg", "df_ak01.1003.jpg", "df_ak01.1005.jpg", "df_ak01.1006.jpg"]

#Pattern to match numbers with 4 or more digits
pattern = re.compile("\d{4,}")

#Extract all numbers
a = [int(pattern.search(x).group(0)) for x in files if pattern.search(x)]
#[1001, 1002, 1003, 1005, 1006]

#Group consecutive numbers together
cons_groups = [list(group) for group in consecutive_groups(a)]
#[[1001, 1002, 1003], [1005, 1006]]

#Create result list
result = [ [len(x), '{}-{}'.format(x[0], x[-1])] for x in cons_groups]
#[[3, '1001-1003'], [2, '1005-1006']]

#Print the result list
for item in result:
    print('{} df_ak01.%04d.jpg {}'.format(item[0], item[1]))
```

The output will be

```
3 df_ak01.%04d.jpg 1001-1003
2 df_ak01.%04d.jpg 1005-1006
```